# SQL - How to automatically choose the smallest id left between 1 and 1000

Tags: mysql, sql

my issues is that i need to make a request on a server that is:

```
https://INeedTheDocsWithThisId="id"
```

"id" need to be between 1 and 1000.
My problem is that i use auto-increment for now, and that leaves holes in ids.

Exemple: I have ids: 1,2,3,4. if I delete the 2. The next one will be 5 and not 2.

How can i make a function that chose automatically the smallest number not-used between 1 and 1000?

thank you guys.

Comment: Why do you say that? ids is used to identify data, why can't we looking for the smallest id number left to use this one, and not have hole in our Datatable ?

Comment: I am not sure why you need this but check my answer.

Comment: @Jilu - `holes in ids` Why do you think that this is problem ?

Comment: @OtoShavadze because the request only allow me to send id between 1 and 1000, and i don't want to overwrite existing ids.

Comment: @dsharew I'm checking thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following SQL can be used to find holes in IDs. It uses joins the table onto itself (aliased as `a` and `b`) and returns the lowest ID + 1 where a record with ID + 1 wasn't found. It is fast, but does not find holes before the first record in your table.

```
SELECT MIN(a.ID) + 1
FROM YourTable a
    LEFT JOIN
       YourTable b
       ON a.id + 1 = b.id
WHERE b.id IS NULL
    AND a.id < 1000;
```

Comment: Thank you, if i understood, i need to make a table a with number going from 1 to 1000 ?

Comment: You need to replace YourTable with the name of the table that holds the IDs you have already used, and change `ID` to be whatever the name of your auto-increment column is

Comment: Ok, what means a and b then ?

Comment: Thank you for the edit, it's more clear now, i'm testing :)

Comment: I like this solution. If you want this to work on a virgin table, too, simply change `AND a.id < 1000` to `AND a.id <= 1000` and `MIN(a.ID) + 1` to `NULLIF(IFNULL(MIN(a.ID),0) + 1, 1001)`.